# Returning a value to a text box with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to add a time stamp to a text box triggered by and event. The text box also has a date picker. The JavaScripts are,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#CCEDate" ).datepicker();
});
```

And

```
function GetCCEDate() {
    $.get('timestamp.php', {},
        function (output) {
            $('#CCEDate').html(output).show();
        }
    );
}
```

The html is:

```
<input name="CCEngaged" id="CCEDate" type="text" style="width: 180px">
```

Or

```
<textarea name="CCEngaged" id="CCEDate" style="overflow: hidden; width: 200px;" rows="1"></textarea>
```

If I use a simple text box, the datepicker works but the `GetCCEDate` does not.  However, if I use a text area, the `GetCCEDate` inserts the time stamp fine but the datepicker does not work on a text area.
What I would like to do is use a simple text box and insert the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for `input` elements:

```
$('#CCEDate').val(output)
```

Comment: That was easy. Thank you!